# Renderscript Library Android Studio 3.3 Cannot find file sdk\build-tools\28.0.0\renderscript\lib\androidx-rs

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

After updating to Android Studio 3.3 Canary 6 with gradle:3.3.0-alpha06 I started getting error Cannot find file sdk\build-tools\28.0.0\renderscript\lib\androidx-rs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am adding this Question for people who may face similar problems.
Name of the file is changed to renderscript-v8 in this update of build-tools. 
I fixed by renaming file back to androidx-rs from **v8-renderscript**